# How to increase the speed of CSV data matching?

Tags: python, csv

I have a scripts that parse two CSV files and compares the first column from one file with the second column from another file. The problem is those files are big and it takes some time to finish the process. The question is how to improve the speed? I tried to use `yield from lines` before the `for` cycle but the problem is then I have convert `lines[1:]` to `list(lines[1:])` as result it makes no sense.

```
def pk():
    with open('way/to/first.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        full_list = []
        for line in lines[1:]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_pk = array[0].replace('"', '')
            full_list.append(list_pk)
        return full_list

def fk():
    with open('way/to/second.csv') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()
        full_list = []
        for line in lines[1:]:
            array = line.split(',')
            list_fk = array[1].replace('"', '')
            full_list.append(list_fk)
        return full_list

def res():
    f = fk()
    p = pk()
    for i in f:
        if i not in p:
            raise AssertionError(f'{i} not found')
```

Comment: It seems you are just looking for the [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) between the columns, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using python's "set difference" to find the elements in set `A` that do not have a match in set `B`:

```
def res():
    fset = set(fk())
    pset = set(pk())
    print('items in F that are missing from P:')
    print(fset - pset)
```